How do I make CapCut stop prompting me to update?
CapCut recently released an update which adds video watermarks unless you purchase a Pro subscription. I've decided to stay on CapCut 5.1.0 to avoid this, but I keep getting prompts to update every time I launch CapCut.
How do I disable the update prompts when I launch CapCut?


One way to stop requests for update is to prevent an applications from accessing the internet.
Set a rule in the firewall manually for the executable, or use a batch script or third-party app to block all executables, including *.exe and *.dll, in the folder.
Some applications require internet access, and if it's needed all the time in CapCut, then this won't work. If access is only needed on occasion, then create two scripts: one to allow access, and another to block it.

Shalom Moishe. I prefer to link directly to the software developer's site instead of Softonic, so I went to Softonic and found their link to the developer's site.  Unfortunately, it resulted in a generic page.  I then performed a web search and found the following GitHub repo.  Does it match the tool you are recommending, or is it different? https://github.com/asheroto/BlockFolderWindowsFirewall

Regrettably, running Folder Firewall Blocker 1.2.00 itself only lists the developer, yunnggoose@gmail.com, who graciously list sources -- but no web site. That said, before using any third-party app, check it at VirusTotal.com. Happy holidays; chag samaiachh.

Chag Sameach! After some digging, I was able to locate the original SourceForge repo, although it's only a little useful: https://web.archive.org/web/20160709221844/https://sourceforge.net/projects/folder-firewall-blocker-ffb/  It was later replaced with a profanely named repo, for reasons unknown.  Although I didn't search exhaustively, I didn't find the source code.

It appears the GitHub repo I found is unrelated, so I'll post that as another answer, in case it helps anyone.  It's provides a PowerShell script, so it naturally includes the source code.

As Dr. Moishe Pippik pointed out, sometimes one must resort to a firewall to prevent update requests.
I found another option to help you block all executables in a folder.  It's a PowerShell script, and thus is open source.  It is available via this GitHub repo:
Block Folder Windows Firewall
https://github.com/asheroto/BlockFolderWindowsFirewall

At it's heart, I believe that script is the basis for the GUI, Folder Firewall Blocker.
